# A Word that means to Have Multiple Powers?

Tags: single-word-requests

Would multipotent work for this since potent does mean power? A word that means to have great potential would be helpful also! It's relating to a person by the way.

Comment: In what context do you mean 'having multiple powers'? Are you meaning a superhero with multiple powers? A software that can be used for multiple uses?

Comment: It’s unlikely that unless she was *omnipotent* she would be able to save anyone in all situations.

Comment: Just so you know, "omnipotent" is quite a bit stronger and means that someone can do literally everything. It's usually used as an attribute of gods, not human beings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use 'prepotent':

> Having great power, force, influence, or authority; pre-eminent in power; more powerful than others; predominant.

[From "prepotent, adj.". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/150513 (accessed October 23, 2015).]

Possibly you could use the rare 'magnipotent':

> Possessing great power.

[From "magnipotent, adj.". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/112347 (accessed October 23, 2015).]

There is also the obsolete and rare adjective 'maximious':

> Having great power.

[From "† maximious, adj.". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/115267 (accessed October 23, 2015).]

Answer (score 1):

*From the comments:* to be **omnipotent** is to be essentially a god. Per *Merriam Webster...*

> **[omnipotent:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/omnipotent)** having virtually unlimited authority or influence.

Answer (score 1):

You’re probably thinking of *pluripotent*. This is used of cells that have the power of developing into multiple different tissues.  So you have all these related words:

- *pluripotence*
- *pluripotency*
- *pluripotent*
- *pluripotential*
- *pluripotentiality*